# throw 404 error with .htaccess file and php

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've got url like `www.web.com/home` and `www.web.com/about` with `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.web.com/page-not-found.html
RewriteRule "home" "index.php?c=home&m=main"
RewriteRule "about" "index.php?c=home&m=about"
```

If I type something like `www.web.com/asd`, `.htaccess` will throw `404 error` and direct `page-not-found.html` file

But, If I type `www.web.com/homesss` or `www.web.com/about/a/b/c`, the `.htaccess` **will not** throw the `404 error`

How do I fix that? I use pure PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use meta characters in rewrite rule to 1:1 match:

^ --- Matches the beginning of the input

$ --- Matches the end of the input

[L] --- Flag last to stop processing rule after match

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.web.com/page-not-found.html

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?c=home&m=main [L]
RewriteRule ^about$ index.php?c=home&m=about [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@JarekBaran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69863644/369434)...

> If I type something like `www.web.com/asd`, `.htaccess` will throw 404 error

Not with the code you've posted...

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://www.web.com/page-not-found.html
> ```

When a request does not map to a resource, the above triggers a 302 (temporary) redirect to the `http://www.web.com/page-not-found.html`. There is no 404 HTTP response. Details of the request that triggered response are lost. `/page-not-found.html` is exposed to the end user. This is generally bad for SEO and delivers a bad user experience.

The 2nd argument to the `ErrorDocument` directive should be a root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash so that the error document is called with an internal subrequest. Apache then responds with a 404 status. The error document is not exposed to the end user.

(Very rarely should an absolute URL be used here.)

For example, it should be like this instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Your're right! I've been getting a problem with this shit now. I changed the `http://www.web.com/page-not-found.html` to `/error/404.html`. But, the browser still redirect to `https://www.web.com/page-not-found.html` although I just clear cache, use another browser, restart the host or everything I can do.

Comment: @VanNguyenKhuu It wouldn't normally be cached (by the browser) since it would have been a 302 (temp) redirect. But that depends on your caching policy and if you are using a CDN. You can look at the network traffic in the browser dev tools to help determine what is happening.